# In google sheets, conditional formatting, need custom formula that looks for range between 2 values

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to change fill colour of one cell based on the value of another.  The colour should change based on range of that cell.  Ex.  Fill cell D8 yellow if value in cell D7 is between 80 and 100.

Comment: The Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting is based on the contents of the cell, rather than another cell.  The only way you could possible get it to work is to have the formula in D8 of =D7.  If you want to hide the number, just format the ink colour to the same as the background colour

Answer (score 3):

Try selecting cell D8 and click Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is:

`=AND($D$7>=80,$D$7<=100)`

Select a yellow background and click Done